# make multidimentional array from JQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, svg

I have list of svg circles with two important attributes: "seat" and "row". The order is random. I need to get all objects and make an array like:

```
arr[row1: seat1, seat2, seat3, ...]
arr[row2: seat1, seat2, seat3, ...]
arr[row3: seat1, seat2, seat3, ...]
arr[row4: seat1, seat2, seat3, ...]
```

in another form: `arr[row][seat]`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var circles = $('circle');
    circles.each(function(){
        var circle = $(this);
        var row = circle.attr('rid');
        var seat = circle.attr('sid');

        rows[row][].push(seat);

    });
    console.log(rows);
});
```

not working.

please advise.
thanks

```
row = $('circle').attr('rid');
seat = $('circle').attr('sid');
```

more explanation:

I have lots of svg circles in this form:

```
<circle class="cls-1" cx="627.93" cy="494.42" r="3.5" fill="grey" id="964" seat="24" row="2" bal="1" group="0" gal="0" part="0" ts="0" sec="0" log="0" yar="0"></circle>
```

I have RID and SID in each line and they are different.

I need to take all circles (1000+) and get their RID and SID and put those two ids into array in the form i wrote

Comment: We need more code to be sure. But from what I see now my first guess is that you didn't initialized the array in the second dimension. i.e. The first time you use it you should initialize it with something like `arr[row] = []`

Comment: None of that even remotely resembles JavaScript syntax except the last line. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a list of circles. 
order is random.
I need to make an multi array like one i gave.

Comment: Also I'm guessing that `arr[row1: seat1, seat2, seat3, ...]` was just illustrative since that's no valid code.

Comment: Yes mark, it's a representation.

Comment: Do you have the circles in DOM and want an array representation in your script?

Comment: Either demonstrate your desired output *in code* or this will probably wind up closed as "unclear what you're asking". "I have list of circles" doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: No, I have list of circles
and I need to make an array to proceed later.

Comment: Sorry, again

I have lots of svg circles in this form: 
<circle class="cls-1" cx="627.93" cy="494.42" r="3.5" fill="grey" id="964" seat="24" row="2" bal="1" group="0" gal="0" part="0" ts="0" sec="0" log="0" yar="0"></circle>

I have RID and SID in each line.

Comment: I need to take all circles (1000+) and get their RID and SID
and put those two ids into array in the form i wrote

Comment: That explanation belongs to the question and not to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

So first you get an array you can iterate through, then you make a loop to put each object in its place, but making sure that you do not try to place something inside `undefined`:

```
circles = $("circle");//We get the circles
arr = []; //Initialize first dimension
circles.each(function() { //This makes the loop
  row = Number($(this).attr("row")); //attr is always a string, we make it a number
  seat = Number($(this).attr("seat"));
  if( typeof arr[seat] === "undefined") //Check if second dimension is initialized, if not, we do it
    arr[seat] = [] // Initializing
  arr[seat][row] = $(this) //Save object
});
```

That's it now you can use it like `arr[2][3]`

Comment: for some reason it puts numbers in array in order.
my file is not ordered.

Comment: It's because of the way they are entered in the array, by using the seat and row number as index. If you would not want it to be this way you would need to decide a fixed number of seats per row and calculate it's place based on the loop index.

Comment: thats why i wanted to use push. can i do it?

Comment: Sure you can, just change `arr[seat][row] = $(this)` for `arr[seat].push($(this))`. Although this is not intuitive, I would change the order to `arr[row][seat]`.

Comment: what about the row then?
i need to seat to row.  i need to make first rows. in each row seats. 
`array[row1][seat, seat2, seat3, seat200, seat11]`...

Comment: Yeah you should change seat for row in the example and it would be that way.

Comment: Also I think you would need an object instead of an array as second dimensio or you would end up with an array full of undefineds

Comment: Just change the initilizer of the second dimension from `arr[seat] = []` to `arr[seat] = {}` you can use it just the same but it will be internally different

Comment: i cannot use push to object

Comment: You're right, also you will not get it full of undefines if you are pushing, my bad. Although this do applies on the rows instead of seat which you are not pushing although it doesn't actually matter if you hava a consecutive number of rows